# & was unexpected at this time

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file that is supposed to set some variables at the beginning.

```
for /f %%A in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^| find /i "bit"') do set "OSARCH=%%A"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%B in ('wmic product where "name like 'Microsoft .NET%'" get name') do set "DNVER=%%B"
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion' do set "IEFULLVER=%%C"
set IEVER=%IEFULLVER:~0,4%
```

If I run these in CMD prompt, (substituting %%A for %A etc), they work as expected, but when I run the batch file, the first line runs as expected and then I get an `& was unexpected at this time` error.
I'm thinking it might be to do with the `%` after `.NET`, but it has to be there otherwise the wmi query won't return the value I need.

Comment: Why is the third line missing a right parenthesis?  What happens if, after the first line, you add: `ECHO %OSARCH%`, and after the current second line, you add, `ECHO %DNVER%`, and after the current third line, you add, `ECHO %IEFULLVER%`,  and after the current 4th line, `ECHO %IEVER%`?  (Even if you still get the error, it may be nice to see where you get the error, compared to some of the other output that may exist.)

Comment: It's missing the parenthesis because I'm a plank and didnt notice the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "& was unexpected at this time" error

There are two mistakes in your batch file.

Mistake 1:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%B in ('wmic product where "name like 'Microsoft .NET%'" get name') do set "DNVER=%%B"
```

The above command needs to have the single `%` after `NET` escaped. Use `%%` instead:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%B in ('wmic product where "name like 'Microsoft .NET%%'" get name') do set "DNVER=%%B"
```

Mistake 2:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion' do set "IEFULLVER=%%C"
```

The above command is missing a `)` before `do`. It should be:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion') do set "IEFULLVER=%%C"
```

Working batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%A in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^| find /i "bit"') do set "OSARCH=%%A"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%B in ('wmic product where "name like 'Microsoft .NET%%'" get name') do set "DNVER=%%B"
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion') do set "IEFULLVER=%%C"
echo %OSARCH%
echo %DNVER%
echo %IEFULLVER%
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
64-bit
4.5.2
11.0.9600.17691
```

---

#### Escaping Percents

> The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters
>   and FOR parameters.
>
> To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:
>
> ```
> %%
> ```

Source [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your answer, fixing the mistakes have worked perfectly. After reading about FOR on SS64 several times last night, it just didn't sink in that doubling the % character applied to the string as well as the parameters.